# MYSQL: BASIC SELECT with != statemenet

Tags: mysql, select

```
SELECT id, company_id, user_id, valid_until, price 
FROM  `classifieds` 
WHERE  `user_id` = 1
AND  `valid_until` >  now()
AND  `price` = -2
```

this query gives me one row, and it works ok...

as soon as i add a statement

```
SELECT id, company_id, user_id, valid_until, price 
FROM  `classifieds` 
WHERE  `user_id` = 1
AND  `valid_until` >  now()
AND  `price` = -2
AND  `company_id` != 23
```

it gives me nothing!!!

the row I am getting in first query has company_id NULL

```
id  company_id  user_id valid_until price
35136   NULL    1   2012-02-12 08:06:37 -2
```

Please advise

EDIT:

I don't want rows that have company_id NULL. I want ALL rows (NULL and not NULL) except for (company_id) value 23.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Data_Manipulation_Language

Comment: @todda.speot.is: what's your point? Can you help me with an answer?

Comment: His point was that what you get is the correct answer. `NULL` is never equal to anything, but it's not *unequal* to anything, either. Tri-value logic. If you want to test for `NULL`, you always have to use `IS (NOT) NULL`

Comment: I know that. but I don't want to test for null... I want to test for value 23 (null or not null). But it seems I solved the problem with adding the is NULL too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id, company_id, user_id, valid_until, price 
FROM  `classifieds` 
WHERE  `user_id` = 1
AND  `valid_until` >  now()
AND  `price` = -2
AND  (`company_id` IS NULL OR `company_id` != 23)
```

this seems to do the trick